# Django object not iterable, why?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I want display `username` if he click on `i want join` button using ajax. 
I have html that look like this :

```
    <div class="who_come">
       <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" id="joinToEventForm">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <p align="left"><b ><button type="submit">I want join</button></b></p></b></p>
       </form>
       {% for u in who_come %}
       <p><a href="profile/{{u.visiter}}">{{u.visiter}}</a></p>
       {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

i use this code to produce my ajax :

```
$('#joinToEventForm').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check

   $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       data:{
           csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}'
       },
       success : function () {
           alert("You are on Envent")
       }
   });
});
```

it code works, and write to database what i need, but it return to me 500 error code with `TypeError: 'WhoComeOnEvent' object is not iterable`. I can't understand what is a problem

it is my model:

```
class WhoComeOnEvent(models.Model):
   visiter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='WhoComeOnEvent')
   which_event = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='WhoComeOnEvent')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s go to %s' % (self.visiter.username, self.which_event.subject)
```

it is my view :

```
def p(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, pk=pk)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    comment = Comments.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    who_come = WhoComeOnEvent.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    if request.is_ajax():
        who_come = WhoComeOnEvent.objects.create(
            visiter=user,
            which_event=post.topic

        )

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.creator = user
            comment.save()
            comment = Comments.objects.create(
                body=form.cleaned_data.get('body'),
                creator=user,

            )
            return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post, 'topic': topic, 'comment': comment,
                                                 'form': form, 'who_come': who_come})
    else:
        form = CustomCommentForm()
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post, 'topic': topic, 'comment': comment,
                                         'form': form, 'who_come': who_come})
```

I use `WhoComeOnEvent.objects.filter`, as far as i know it may be iterable. I was try use `__iter__` and it doesn't help me. I was try use `object.filter(...).values()`, but it too do not help. I think may be i made wrong logic in ajax functionality.  Please don't be mad if it stupid question, i use ajax first time at my life.

#### Edit

I solved 500 error and iterable problem by replacing

```
{% for u in who_come %}
 <p><a href="profile/{{u.visiter}}">{{u.visiter}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

to

```
{% for u in who_come.visiter.all %}
 <p><a href="profile/{{u.username}}">{{u.username}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

but it not display link on user in html

Comment: `objects.create()` returns a single object which is not iterable. Perhaps you want to put the `who_come = WhoComeOnEvent.objects.filter(pk=pk)` statement after creating the new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see, if this condition is true:

```
if request.is_ajax()
```

then who_come is going to be a WhoComeOnEvent.objects.create object and that's not an iterable!

Comment: yes, you are right, i solved problem of iterable objects, but it still doesn't display username on html

Comment: @Anton - If this answer solves your question then you should consider accepting it, if you have further problems you should raise them as a new question complete with what you have tried and researched.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send back something useful to change the HTML after the AJAX call.

**Solution**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def p(request, pk):
    # your existing code
    if request.is_ajax():
        # change variable name
        who_come_obj = # same create code

        visitors_usernames = []
        for w in who_come:
            visitors_usernames.append(w.visiter.username)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(visitors_usernames))
```

In Javascript AJAX success method:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(data) {
    //seems more useful try to use convertation
    var to_json = JSON.stringify(data);
    var usernames = JSON.parse(to_json);
    var html_str = '';

    for (var i=0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
      html_str += '<p><a href="profile/' + usernames[i] + '">' + usernames[i] + '</a></p>';
    }

    $('#who_come_links').html(html_str);
  }
});
```

Finally, wrap the links with a div with id `who_come_links` in HTML

```
<div id="who_come_links">
  {% for u in who_come %}
    <p><a href="profile/{{u.visiter.username}}">{{u.visiter.username}}</a></p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but : `for u in who_come.visiter.all(): AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'visiter'`, seems wierd, because in `who_come` visiter is exist

Comment: Yeah, it was a queryset object. Not a model instance. Therefore, vister does not exist in there. I have updated the answer.

Comment: in ajax you use `var usernames = JSON.parse(data);` but it has only csrf, and when i push on `i want to join` button it return response is empty list and in browser console `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: did you add `data` argument like `success: function(data)` ?

Comment: oh, sorry, my fault, but it still do not display anything

Comment: open Dev Console and add `console.log(data);` in `success: function` of AJAX and see if the data is coming or not.

Comment: @SuchinKukreja it return empty list, but in database i has few row

Comment: That is because your filter isn't correct on `WhoComeOnEvent`.

Comment: I dont know what you're trying to achieve. I think either the filter or model fields aren't correct.

Comment: i try to achive displaying name of user that click on `i want join` button

Comment: Then you need to filter based on `which_event` rather than `pk`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works, but not as i want) after clicking in the button in console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1.` Seems that `"  '  " ` in list `['username']`, how to delete `"  '  " `?